# Is it possible to put under guardianship someone who is not impaired?

Tags: france, power-of-attorney

My brother-in-law have a track record of loss of documents, debt, and is otherwise unable to ensure his own self-being or manage his property.

While searching for solution, I came accross "Mise sous curatelle" (guardianship/curatorship), which, if I understand right, mean all the administrative, and manage his property for him, in the exclusive interest of the curatee. That sound like a perfect solution.

However, it seems curatorship is reserved for case where the potential curatee is physically impaired, either by sickness, disability, or heavy usage of drugs. None of thoses apply to my brother in law.

The law talk about a medical certificate delivered by a authorized doctor. While finding a authorized doctor, and paying the examination is not a problem, it seems to me the report will be negative, since there is no physical impairement.

My brother in law, however, have admitted himself he may have psychological trouble, and accepted to get a therapist. If the therapist conclude there is a defined trouble, is it possible to use this to allow the guardianship?

*Note*: The brother in law is aware that I am searching a similar solution, and have no direct objections, especially if he can appeal the solution by himself when he got everything under control again. Curatorship seems to be the right thing on every plan at this point.

Comment: Are you talking about a solution in which the subject is declared incompetent so that he is *not allowed* to manage his own affairs, regardless of any objection he might have?  Or merely a solution in which he *agrees* to grant authority to a trustee/curator to manage his affairs?

Comment: As he is not opposed to the idea, a solution where he agrees to grant authority, and where he keep a part of his authority (which is how I understood curatorship) is fine. A third party (judge or other state representative) would be a bonus, as to ensure impartiality of the curator.

Comment: A "curator" may have fiduciary obligations under French law.  (I.e., just agreeing to assume the responsibilities commits the curator to act only in the interests of the beneficiary.)  In the U.S. trustees are guilty of fraud (and, if they are a professional, also violation of their professional obligations) if they abuse their discretion to take any action not in the interest of the beneficiary.

Comment: Yes, the situation in the immediate family have degenerated to a point nobody trust the other to do the right thing, that's why a third party, professional curator, seems to be the only thing that will really beneficit my brother in law. Everybody want to take the same role, without the fiduciary obligation, and I feel it will be used to spite the other part of the family, without real care for the poor soul...

Comment: The problem is, can he really be put under curatorship, since he is physically capable of representing himself, even if he is utterly lost and admit he need help.

Comment: Hopefully this is where somebody familiar with French law steps in with a real answer....  In U.S. law it's just a matter of him granting somebody power of attorney.

Comment: If someone has to be his curator, probably there will be the need of some kind of judicially approved incapacitation (otherwise, while the curator was managing your BiL funds, he could be signing himself into buying a new car). I saw some info about it in Spain, with a NGO managing the funds of people in similar situations (they would provide with a limited money each few days, would approve any contract, etc.). I would start looking by talking to social workers, they may have some experience with that.